# Meta link not showing up on any Stack Exchange site profiles

Tags: support, profile-page, per-site-meta

I'm not entirely certain when this occurred, though I'm suspicious that this might have first shown up when the new profiles were introduced. I just can't verify that at all. And since the link is missing from both new and old profiles, I just have to assume it's unrelated. On my most active site, and a few others, things are normal:

Stack Overflow:

[image]

And [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour):

[image]

are unaffected.

But [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour) and [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour) are affected:

[image]

[image]

The list of my Stack Exchange sites where the Meta link has vanished:

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) (the link is now there! See edit below...)
- Computer Science
- [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) (the link is now there! More on that below...)
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)
- MathOverflow
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)

Notice that this is both new and old profiles. I first observed this on Reverse Engineering. So naturally I typed in the meta site address and navigated to it 'manually'. I posted my observation figuring this had something to with the recent changes (and that it might simply have been moved to some place that was different from every other site). Once I navigated back to the main site profile, the meta link was there! And has been there ever since. This led me to poke around all of my site profiles to see if something was really up, or I was just having some weird dyslexic moment.

I've done a search and nobody else seems to be reporting this by any means that I can find. This might be a feature of some kind, but then why am I seeing the meta link on several other of my Stack Exchange site profiles?

**Edit:** It seems that somebody else attempting to visit the meta profile of a site causes the link to appear, even if I've never attempted it myself. Super User now displays the meta link on my main profile.

**Update:** Well, I can see we have a new layout to the Activity page, and all of the meta site links have vanished yet again. I guess I should be glad I still have Meta showing up in my *Accounts* list. After some testing, the bigger issue this time is that the appear to be **permanently** gone. Before I could at least visit the meta site, return to the main site, and it would be there. That doesn't appear to be the case this time.

**UPDATE:** *(thanks [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard-wearing-mask-v2))* The meta links have been moved off the main page and into a drop down:

[image]

Comment: I can see a Meta link on my SuperUser profile.  Perhaps it's specific to your account, or a small number of accounts?

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking something like this as well. Glad that it is verified that *others* can see the link. Would you mind taking a look at SO and maybe a couple of others, just to be sure...?

Comment: That's because you don't have meta profile on those sites yet e.g. http://meta.superuser.com/users/318262

Comment: So just to be clear, because I'm about 99% certain that that link used to be there for every profile: If someone doesn't manually go visit their respective Meta, they don't get a link to the Meta? Something must be wrong here. How are new users supposed to ever find the meta? Use the secret code of typing in the address?  That doesn't seem right....  I believe that profile creation used to automatically occur when you clicked on the link.

Comment: As Nick says: *...if they're on the list they get a link on their profile*

Comment: How much rep do you have on those sites?

Comment: It varies. Even on low rep/low visit sites like the German beta, I can see the meta link. I'm not sure what the pattern is.

Comment: It did not vanish, it moved into "Profiles" drop down, in the top right corner: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PwXH.png (you can edit the question with up-to-date screenshots, but please roll back the recent edits)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2, I've updated the post with your image. Thanks. I'm leaving the edits as they are not precisely wrong, the links are (presumably) permanently off the Activity page and in a drop down now.

Comment: So is this now a feature request asking to undo the drop down?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2, Nope, nothing like that. Noticed the link was gone. Updated the post. Had it pointed it out that it's in a drop down now. Updated again. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 8):

I think that until you visit meta on a specific site, you don't have an account there. When i manually went to your meta profile for Physics.SE, it was nonexistent. I was able to reproduce this with my own account on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/6899/scimonster), where i have never visited meta. So this appears to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Yes, pretty much this.

Comment: Then I think this must be broken. How are new users ever supposed to know that they can participate in a meta?

Comment: Most users don't need to participate in the meta. But it is linked in the sites drop down and mentioned in the help centre as well has having a badge for it. There are plenty of places where users are made aware of the meta.

Comment: @Scimonster, also this doesn't explain why some users can see the link on my profile, but I can't, as is clearly the case.

Comment: @Oded, That's not a good reason for that link to disappear (if I'm correct in assuming that it was always there).

Comment: @ouflak When can other people see the link but you can't?

Comment: See the comments on the question above.

Comment: @ouflak  dsolimano said he could see it on his *own* profile. And now i can see your Super User meta link, because you've since visited it.

Comment: @ouflak - I don't follow. The link doesn't exist if a user never went to the meta site. It doesn't disappear from anywhere.

Comment: Then how is it that others can see the link on some of those profile pages that I cannot see? Are you saying that if another user has *their own* meta account, then they can see a meta link on my page even if I have never been on that meta page? If so, that's kind of crazy.

Comment: @ouflak why strange? When a user who is logged in to a main site  visits its meta site for the first time, account on that meta is automatically created in that instant. There is a process running every few minutes that skims through meta profiles, and making sure everyone with meta profile will have a link to it from their main profile. Makes total sense to me.